# Rotating line smoothly towards vector (2D)

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I'm writing a simple computer animation, which is a line that rotates around a fixed point at the center of that line. The amount of rotation is based on a gradient noise algorithm (OpenSimplex noise). The line has an origin [x,y] and a nr of the animation frame. These three values plugged into OpenSimplex noise give a rotation value. This part is working perfectly.

The problem is I want to make the line appear to follow the mouse cursor, depending on how far the mouse cursor is from the line. The cursor has coordinates [mx, my] (which change for every frame of animation). I can easily rotate the line and point straight towards the cursor. But I'm having difficulties factoring in the distance. To clarify; the line is rotation on the gradient noise and the mouse cursor alters that rotation to make the line (at [x, y]) point at [mx, my].

Also, the line has an 180 degree identity, so the closest end should point towards the mouse.

Basically what I'm doing now is taking "rotation line" plus "rotation mouse". If it is between 90 and 270 deg the back of the line is closest to the cursor, otherwise the front (for simplicity this is not included in the example code below). So I then take the difference, factor in the distance and substract or add it to the rotation of the line. And this works fairly well except for some artifacts.

```
let r = OpenSimplexNoise(x, y, frame); // gives current original rotation
let frame = 68; // whichever frame
let x = 60; // some fixed coordinate of line
let y = 60; // some fixed coordinate of line
let mouseX = 10; // changes when the mouse moves
let mouseY = 10; // changes when the mouse moves
let mouseRadius = 200;
let width = 100;
let height = 1;

function distance (x, y, cx, cy) {
    return Math.sqrt((x - cx) * (x - cx) + (y - cy) * (y - cy));
}

function angle (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    let dx = x1 - x2;
    let dy = y1 - y2;

    return 360 + (Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI);
}

if (distance(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) <= mouseRadius) {
    let dist = distance(x, y, mouseX, mouseY);
    let mouseR = angle(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) % 360;

    let near = (mouseRadius - dist) / mouseRadius;
    let far = 1 - near;

    r = (r * far + near * mouseR) % 360;
}

// r now includes mouse
```

A live version:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ruudt/56pk2wd1/1/

The problem lies in the cases where the mouse passes from being left to right of perpendicular to the (original rotation) line. Here the calculation will nominate the other end as "closests", then calculate the distance and apply this to the rotation. This results in the line jumping from pointing slightly left of the cursor to right of the cursor (or vice versa).

**Is there a way to fix this?**

I've made an image to illustrate the situation.

- The red line represents the line using only the rotation of the gradient noise
- The black line is the line that also includes mouse position
- the blue arc is the mouse rotation value (right end is origin)

line rotation:
 [image: img]

Comment: Please add a starting point in code. This helps in solving the problem quickly.

Comment: @Roy, I've updated the question to include some code

Comment: What would you like to happen when the mouse pointer approaches the line from the "wrong" direction?